# Calling context.getResources() returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

So I am trying to get a string resource in my project but when I called `context.getResources().getString(...)`, I get a `NullPointerException`. In debug mode, I found out that the context isn't null but looking at its members, I found out that `mResources` was null. Why are the resources not loaded for the activity context?

**EDIT**

Apparently, this is what triggered the Exception

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}


public class SomeClass {

    private final Context mContext;

    public SomeClass(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    }
}
```

I had to move the initialization of `someClass` to after `super.onCreate()` as suggested by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware). Thanks.

Comment: How did you instantiate the activity you're using as a context? Where exactly in the activity lifecycle are you calling `getResources()`?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing correct ID, that belongs String.xml?

Comment: @laalto instantiate like `onCreate`?

Comment: Instantiate as in creating an object of a class. Did the framework do it or did you use `new` yourself?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I had to guess, you are trying to call this in an initializer. Do not attempt to use `getResources()` before the `super.onCreate()` call in your activity returns.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks. I have a member in the activity that initializes by default and I was trying to call the method from its constructor.